# Using [array] in a class based DSC resource

Tags: class, powershell, dsc

I have been creating a few class based custom DSC resources and I am running into the following issue:

Whenever I try to use an array as input for my resource, I get an error.

For example

```
DscProperty(Mandatory)]
[array]$Products
```

Would result in the following error when I try to create a MOF file using my resource:

> Write-NodeMOFFile : Invalid MOF definition for node 'nodename':
>   Exceptioncalling "ValidateInstanceText" with "1" argument(s):
>   "Convert property 'Products' value from type 'STRING[]' to type 'INSTANCE' failed.

The input object for `$Products` would be (for example):

```
$Products = @("Windows server 2012", "Windows SQL Server", "Windows 8.1")
```

I honestly have no idea why the `Write-NodeMOFFile` function would try to convert the array (it should not need converting, right?) and even if it needed to be converted - why would it convert an array from `STRING[]` to `INSTANCE`?

Anyone has a clue as to why this happens?
The only way I got it to work was by creating a long string from my array of strings and then seperating them within the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare array like this :

```
[string[]]$product="ddd","dq","dqq"
```

Comment: Thanks saftargholi! That did the job!